# while configuring sharepoint 2013 we get the error One or more types failed to load

Tags: sharepoint-2013

we are installing sharepoint 2013 on a windows server 2012 with sql server 2014. after successfully installation of sharepoint and when I want to configure the product we get the error: "One or more types failed to load. please refer to upgrade log for more details."
how I can solve this problem.
It's worth to notice that my domain user account has all permissions in sql server and also is a member of administrator group in windows.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a variety of issues.  Can you find more information in the Application or the SharePoint Log?

Here is a common problem with the install process with SharePoint 2013:
[App Fabric Not Installed or Wrong Version](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/111439/error-creating-site-collection-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-appl)

However to get more detailed information to your issue, download the ULS viewer
[here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44020). Re-run your install with the ULS viewer running and you'll hopefully find an more detailed error that will help you troubleshoot.